# Как в Python 3 при try выполнить комманду а в except вывести ошибку и продолжить выполнение программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, синтаксис, try-catch

Как в Python 3 при try выполнить комманду а в except вывести ошибку и продолжить выполнение программы

Пример:

```
error= ' '
try:
    print (str(1/0))
except:
    error = 'ошибка номер ....'
    print("ошибка с текстом, строка, линия и т.п. тип ошибки(что пишет компилятор): "+str(error))

#продолжает исполнение
try:
    print (str(0/0))
except:
    error = 'ошибка номер ....'
    print("ошибка с текстом, строка, линия и т.п. тип ошибки(что пишет компилятор): "+str(error))

#продолжает исполнение
try:
    print (str(1+1))
except:
    error = 'ошибка номер ....'
    print("ошибка с текстом, строка, линия и т.п. тип ошибки(что пишет компилятор): "+str(error))
```

Comment: `except Exception as exc: print(exc)` для начала

Comment: И вообще просто `except:` почти никогда не стоит писать, так как вы рискуете потерять возможность штатно выключить программу (перехватываются исключения SystemExit и KeyboardInterrupt)

Comment: А можно ли выводить сообщения ошибок типа и как:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\1\fb\vremm_dla_prob.py", line 15, in <module>
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("email") #находим поле с email
  check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"email"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86)

Comment: import traceback; traceback.print_exc()

Answer (score 2):

```
import traceback;

error= ' '
try:
    print (str(1/0))
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    error = 'ошибка номер ....'
    print("ошибка с текстом, строка, линия и т.п. тип ошибки(что пишет компилятор): "+str(error))
    print ("traceback.print_exc():")
    traceback.print_exc()
    print("____")    
#продолжает исполнение
try:
    print (str(0/0))
except Exception as exc:
    print ("traceback.print_exc():")
    traceback.print_exc()
    print("____")
    print(exc)
    error = 'ошибка номер ....'
    print("ошибка с текстом, строка, линия и т.п. тип ошибки(что пишет компилятор): "+str(error))

#продолжает исполнение
try:
    print (str(1+1))
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    error = 'ошибка номер ....'
    print("ошибка с текстом, строка, линия и т.п. тип ошибки(что пишет компилятор): "+str(error))
```

с помощью [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal)

Answer (score 1):

**А.** Вам нужно понимать, что если вы делаете `try except` то код прервётся только в том случае, если вы ЯВНО прервёте его исполнение, к примеру, командой `exit()` в блоке `except`. То есть, в такой конструкции:

```
aab = '123'
b = 3

try:
     print(aab+b)
except:
     print('123')
print('Я бегу бабу ягу')
print('Заяц - Волк')
```

В случае **"без ошибки"**, выполниться блок `try` и весь остальной код, за гранью блока `try except`. В случае **ошибки** - выполняется `except`, и далее код за гранью `try except`.
В конкретно этом примере два последних принта:

```
print('Я бегу бабу ягу')
print('Заяц - Волк')
```

выполнятся в любом случае!

**Б.** Вывести текст ошибки можно принципиально двумя путями:

Объявить `except` как переменную и эту переменную "распечатать":

```
except as err:
    print(err)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

--- ИЛИ ---

Импортировать библиотеку `traceback` и распечатать "полный путь" ошибки:

```
import traceback    
except:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первый вариант печатает только "последний" пункт ошибки, чаще всего этого хватает. Но иногда, необходим детальный путь - traceback

Вот тут можно почитать про try except - https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/isklyucheniya-v-python-konstrukciya-try-except-dlya-obrabotki-isklyuchenij.html

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит пользоваться `print` для вывода отладочной информации.
Лучше написать один раз удобный конфиг для logging и пользоваться им.

Вывод сообщений об исключениях можно организовать следующим образом:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

try:
    raise RuntimeError('Ошибка исполнения!')
except RuntimeError:
    log.exception('Это сообщение об ошибке:')

print('Продолжаем выполнение...')
```

Результат:

```
Это сообщение об ошибке:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
RuntimeError: Ошибка исполнения!
Продолжаем выполнение...
```